# How to effeciently update table that depends on previous records

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-update

My SQL Server table looks like this:

```
id  Distance        a   b   Grp
--------------------------------
1   0.0000000000    100 114 NULL
2   0.1000000000    64  125 NULL
3   0.1000000000    88  100 NULL
4   0.1000000000    65  125 NULL
5   0.1000000000    63  64  NULL
6   0.1000000000    65  66  NULL
7   0.2000000000    63  66  NULL
8   0.2000000000    10  61  NULL
9   0.2000000000    19  61  NULL
10  0.2000000000    30  61  NULL
11  0.2000000000    10  65  NULL
12  0.2000000000    10  94  NULL
13  0.2000000000    19  65  NULL
14  0.2000000000    19  94  NULL
15  0.2000000000    30  94  NULL
16  0.2000000000    60  94  NULL
17  0.2000000000    61  94  NULL
```

The `Grp` column should be filled as follows

- first record `Grp` is 1
- if the next row's values of a & b are in any of the previous rows, then it will take the first rows `Grp` value
- if the next row's values of a & b are not in any of the previous rows, then `Grp` value will be `max Grp + 1`
- if the record id = 3 then the value of b = 100 which exists in the previous rows, the first one it appears in was id = 1 which is `Grp = 1` so the `Grp` will be 1 for id 3

This is what my table should look like:

```
id  Distance        a   b   Grp
--------------------------------
1   0.0000000000    100 114 1
2   0.1000000000    64  125 2
3   0.1000000000    88  100 1
4   0.1000000000    65  125 2
5   0.1000000000    63  64  2
6   0.1000000000    65  66  2
7   0.2000000000    63  66  2
8   0.2000000000    10  61  3
9   0.2000000000    19  61  3
10  0.2000000000    30  61  3
11  0.2000000000    10  65  2
12  0.2000000000    10  94  3
13  0.2000000000    19  65  2
14  0.2000000000    19  94  3
15  0.2000000000    30  94  3
16  0.2000000000    60  94  3
17  0.2000000000    61  94  3
```

I have built this script that works fine, but it's extremely slow, any way I can get it better (*without a loop*)?

```
DECLARE @T AS TABLE  
              (
                  id int IDENTITY, 
                  Distance decimal(18, 10), 
                  a int, 
                  b int, 
                  Grp int
              )

INSERT INTO @T(Distance, a, b)
    SELECT Distance, a, b 
    FROM MyTable 
    ORDER BY Distance

UPDATE @T
SET Grp = 1 
WHERE id = 1

DECLARE @i int = 2, @max int, @min int, 
        @grp int, @a int, @b int, @maxgrp int = 1

SELECT @max = MAX(id) FROM @T

WHILE @i <= @max 
BEGIN
    SELECT @a = a, @b = b 
    FROM @T 
    WHERE id = @i

    SELECT @min = MIN(id) 
    FROM @T 
    WHERE id < @i AND a IN (@a, @b) OR b IN (@a, @b)

    SELECT @grp = grp 
    FROM @T 
    WHERE id = @min

    IF @grp IS NULL
    BEGIN
        SET @maxgrp = @maxgrp  + 1 
        SET @grp = @maxgrp
    END
    
    UPDATE @T 
    SET Grp = @grp 
    WHERE id = @i

    SET @i = @i + 1
END

SELECT * FROM @T
```

Comment: Why is row 12 group 3? It has a 10, which by that point is a member of both group 2 and group 3?

Comment: row 12 has a=10 and b=94..  the first record any of these values showed (smallest ID ) was record with id = 8 which has Grp = 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An answer using recursion instead of a loop.

- https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=5410e95927e81d41f27f1d569b5d3cd3

First, identify the first row any value (from a or b) appears on...

```
CREATE TABLE #node(
  row_id       INT,
  old_val      INT,
  new_val      INT,
  link_count   INT
  INDEX node_old_new CLUSTERED (link_count, old_val, new_val, row_id),
);

INSERT INTO
  #node
SELECT
  e.id, twinned.*, COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY e.id)
FROM
  #example  AS e
CROSS APPLY
(
  SELECT e.a AS old_val, e.b AS new_val
  UNION ALL
  SELECT e.b AS old_val, e.a AS new_val
)
  AS twinned
WHERE
  NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT *
      FROM #example AS lookup
     WHERE twinned.new_val IN (lookup.a, lookup.b)
       AND lookup.id < e.id
  )
;
```

Where `link_count = 2`, ***both*** `a` ***and*** `b` appear for the first time on this row, which means this row will start a new group.

Where `link_count = 1`, `new_val` has never been seen previously, but `old_val` has been.  So, once `old_val` has been assigned a group, we can propagate that group to `new_val`.

That's just a tree traversal creating a closure table.

```
WITH
  closure AS
(
  SELECT
    new_val                               AS val,
    DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY row_id)   AS grp,
    row_id                                AS row_id,
    0                                     AS depth
  FROM
    #node
  WHERE
    link_count = 2
  
  UNION ALL
  
  SELECT
    r.new_val,
    c.grp,
    r.row_id,
    c.depth + 1
  FROM
    closure   AS c
  INNER JOIN
    #node     AS r
      ON  r.old_val    = c.val
      AND r.link_count = 1
)
```

Now, for any value in `a` or `b` we can look up the group for that value in the closure table.  We'll likely get two different groups, one from looking up `a` and one from looking up `b`; so, we take the group that was allocated from the earliest row.

```
SELECT
  e.*, g.grp
FROM
  #example   e
CROSS APPLY
(
  SELECT TOP 1
    c.grp
  FROM
    #closure  AS c
  WHERE
    c.val IN (e.a, e.b)
  ORDER BY
    c.row_id
)
  AS g
ORDER BY
  e.id
```

Comment: amazing.. Thanks heaps.. i had to stop my loop after 10 hours and updating on 25% of my records.
your query was 10 min

Comment: @asmgx You're welcome, feel free to upvote and/or accept. Out of interest, how long did each of the three steps take?

Answer (score 0):

If you only need `Grp` to group by it, it can be simplified this way:

```
declare @t table (id int identity, Distance decimal(18,10)
                , a int, b int, Grp int)
insert @t (Distance, a, b)
-- select Distance, a, b From MyTable order by Distance
values
    (0.0,100,114),(0.1, 64,125),(0.1, 88,100),(0.1, 65,125),
    (0.1, 63, 64),(0.1, 65, 66),(0.2, 63, 66),(0.2, 10, 61),
    (0.2, 19, 61),(0.2, 30, 61),(0.2, 10, 65),(0.2, 10, 94),
    (0.2, 19, 65),(0.2, 19, 94),(0.2, 30, 94),(0.2, 60, 94),
    (0.2, 61, 94)

declare @i int, @d float, @a int, @b int, @g int

declare c1 cursor for select * from @t for update of Grp
open c1
fetch next from c1 into @i, @d, @a, @b, @g
update @t set Grp = 1 where current of c1
fetch next from c1 into @i, @d, @a, @b, @g
while @@fetch_status = 0
begin
    update @t set Grp =
        isNull((select top 1 (Grp)
                from @t t2
                where t2.id < @i
                  and (@a in (t2.a , t2.b)
                   or  @b in (t2.a , t2.b)))
                , @i)
    where current of c1
    fetch next from c1 into @i, @d, @a, @b, @g
end
close c1
deallocate c1

-- If you need consecutive Grp numbers ..
declare @u table (id int identity, Grp int)
insert @u (Grp)
select distinct Grp from @t order by Grp

update @t set Grp = u.id
from @t t
join @u u on (u.Grp = t.Grp and u.Grp<>u.id)

select * from @t
```

Answer (score 0):

The following query produces the output you want.

```
WITH t3 as(
  SELECT *
  FROM 
    (SELECT id,Distance,a,b,rnk,
     CASE WHEN rnk > 0 THEN NULL ELSE grp END AS Grp,
     Row_Number() OVER(ORDER BY id) AS seq
     FROM
       (SELECT id,Distance,a,b,rnk,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY rnk ORDER BY id) AS grp
        FROM
         (SELECT id,Distance,a,b,
          ISNULL((SELECT top 1 id FROM tb s2 WHERE s2.id < s1.id AND (s2.a = s1.a OR s2.b = s1.b OR s2.b = s1.a OR s2.a = s1.b)),0) AS rnk
          FROM tb s1) T) T) T
  WHERE Grp > 0
)

SELECT id,Distance,a,b,min(grp)
FROM
  (SELECT distinct * 
  FROM
   (SELECT t1.id,t1.Distance,t1.a,t1.b,t3.grp
   FROM 
     (SELECT id,Distance,a,b,grp,
        ISNULL((SELECT top 1 id FROM tb s2 WHERE s2.id < s1.id AND (s2.a = s1.a OR s2.b = s1.b OR s2.b = s1.a OR s2.a = s1.b)),0) AS rnk
      FROM tb s1) t1
   JOIN tb t2 ON t1.rnk = t2.id

   JOIN t3 ON
     t1.a = t3.a OR t1.a = t3.b OR 

     t1.b = t3.b OR t1.b = t3.a OR
   
     t2.b = t3.b OR t2.b = t3.a OR
   
     t2.a = t3.a OR t2.a = t3.b) t1
     
  UNION ALL  
     
  SELECT id,Distance,a,b,grp
  FROM t3) T
GROUP BY id,Distance,a,b
ORDER BY id
```

Demo in [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=142cc126ccd630f85fcfb6b6a27d8c87)